# Can we monitor iis in a windows server using wmi_exporter metrics

Tags: prometheus, wmi, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager

Looking for an solution to monitor iis using grafana, Prometheus and wmi exporter and also need an idea on creating an custom alert when iis goes down or reset.
Suggest some example alerts related to iis and need to know wmi exporter metrics which is related iis

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For example i'm going to write an Prometheus custom alert for vm reboot event .it should be triggers an mail when vm gets rebooted with humanize timestamp. I need an example or metrics for these